# Hourly Snapshot of a table in SQL query in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, psql

I have a table in BQ called `order_events`. `closed` is the final state of the order. Once a order is `closed` it can not be changed to other state. `open`, `pending` `processing` are intermediate states of order & can be interchanged any number of times unless `closed`. The `order_events` has the history of state changes.

I want to group by `client_id`, date and hour of the day with the number of `open`, `pending` `processing` at the start of the hour. I should only consider the last state of the order. If the order went `open` -> `processing` -> `open`, then i will consider `open`.

There can be cases of overflow, say an order is `open` at `2021-05-26 05:24`, if i run the query at 2021-05-26 07:00 then I need to count the last state of the order at `2021-05-26 05:24` since its still `open` & nothing has happened.

I tried partitioning by `order_id` & then `sum` the result with a `case` but I am not able to get it right.

```
order_id  │ client_id │ ts                      │ status 
══════════╪═══════════╪═════════════════════════╪════════
1         │ newman    │ 2021-05-26 03:00:28 UTC │ open      
1         │ newman    │ 2021-05-26 04:24:28 UTC │ pending
1         │ newman    │ 2021-05-26 04:54:28 UTC │ processing
1         │ newman    │ 2021-05-26 05:24:28 UTC │ closed
3         │ buday     │ 2021-05-26 06:24:28 UTC │ processing
4         │ buday     │ 2021-05-26 06:34:28 UTC │ open
5         │ buday     │ 2021-05-26 06:44:28 UTC │ open
4         │ buday     │ 2021-05-26 06:54:28 UTC │ pending
```

Expected output:

```
 client_id │ date      │ hour │ open │ processing │ pending
═══════════╪═══════════╪══════╪══════╪════════════╪════════
newman     | 2021-05-26| 3    | 1    | 0          | 0
buday      | 2021-05-26| 3    | 0    | 0          | 0
newman     | 2021-05-26| 4    | 1    | 0          | 0
buday      | 2021-05-26| 4    | 0    | 0          | 0
newman     | 2021-05-26| 5    | 0    | 1          | 0
buday      | 2021-05-26| 5    | 0    | 0          | 0
newman     | 2021-05-26| 6    | 0    | 0          | 0
buday      | 2021-05-26| 6    | 0    | 0          | 0
newman     | 2021-05-26| 7    | 0    | 0          | 0
buday      | 2021-05-26| 7    | 1    | 1          | 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this query should do what you are looking for. The only inconvenience is that I couldn't find a way to add inexistent information. For instance, client_id "buday" does not have any entry at 3, so I don't think it will be possible to have a line with open=0, processing=0 and pending=0 (same for "newman" at 6).

```
WITH data as (
SELECT 1 as order_id, "newman" as client_id, timestamp("2021-05-26 03:00:28 UTC") as ts, "open" as status UNION ALL
SELECT 1 as order_id, "newman" as client_id, "2021-05-26 04:24:28 UTC" as ts, "pending" as status UNION ALL
SELECT 1 as order_id, "newman" as client_id, "2021-05-26 04:54:28 UTC" as ts, "processing" as status UNION ALL
SELECT 1 as order_id, "newman" as client_id, "2021-05-26 05:24:28 UTC" as ts, "closed" as status UNION ALL
SELECT 3 as order_id, "buday" as client_id, "2021-05-26 06:24:28 UTC" as ts, "processing" as status UNION ALL
SELECT 4 as order_id, "buday" as client_id, "2021-05-26 06:34:28 UTC" as ts, "open" as status UNION ALL
SELECT 5 as order_id, "buday" as client_id, "2021-05-26 06:44:28 UTC" as ts, "open" as status UNION ALL
SELECT 4 as order_id, "buday" as client_id, "2021-05-26 06:54:28 UTC" as ts, "pending" as status 
)

, data_prep as (
SELECT client_id, 
date(ts) date, 
EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ts) as hour,
status,
FROM data)

, agg_data as (
SELECT client_id, 
date, 
hour, 
LAST_VALUE(status) OVER (PARTITION BY client_id, date, hour ORDER BY date desc) last_status
FROM data_prep)


SELECT 
client_id, 
date, 
hour, 
open, 
processing, 
pending
FROM agg_data
PIVOT( COUNT(distinct last_status) for last_status IN ("open" as open, "processing" as processing, "pending" as pending))
ORDER BY hour
```

[image]

NOTE: As you can see in the last part of the query, I'm taking advantage of the new feature called [PIVOT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#pivot_operator).